# Bound inner product of $\langle w,X \rangle$, where $X$ is uniformly distributed in a unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X\sim U\left(B_0^m(1)\right),$ where $U(\cdot)$ denotes uniform distribution and $B_x^m(r)$ denotes a ball of radius $r$ with center $x$ in $\mathbb{R^m}.$ We also have a fixed vector $w\in B_0^m(1)$.

1. The first problem now for me is to decide the sub-Gaussian parameter $\nu^2$ of $\langle w,X\rangle$, in another word, to find the upper bound of $\langle w,X\rangle$.

It is easy to see that since $X$ is a bounded random vector, we can prove $\nu^2\sim O(1)$ by a brute bounding. My question is that since $X$ is uniform in a unit ball, we might be able to do better here, and if it possible for us to bound $\nu^2\sim O\left(\frac{1}{m}\right)$?

2. A problem from the other side is that if the norm of $w$ is at least $\delta$, how to find the lower bound of $\langle w,X\rangle$?

I guess the lower bound could be of the form: for $\forall \varepsilon>0, \mathbb{P}(\langle w,X\rangle\ge\varepsilon)\ge e^{-1.5\varepsilon^2m/\delta^2}.$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the first problem, I have found answer in [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3567380), and the second problem remains to be solved now.

Comment: The second bound is even easier, which can be bound by a Gaussian. Here $\delta\in(2\varepsilon,1/2)$.